# left join outputs incorrect first block of data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get data from two tables: `users` and `posts` using `left join`.

```
$items = '';
$sql = "
SELECT u.id as uid
     , u.name as uname
     , p.id as pid
     , p.date as pdate
     , p.title as ptitle
     , p.user as puser 
  FROM users u 
  LEFT 
  JOIN posts p 
    ON u.id = p.user
 WHERE u.role = 'mod'
 GROUP 
    BY p.title;";  

$stmt = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $date = strtotime($row['pdate']);
    $date = date("d-m-Y", $date);
    $items.= "<div class='itemp' data-id=" . $row['pid'] . " data-user='" . $row['uname'] . "'>" . 
    "<span class='spandate'>" . $date . "</span>" . 
    "<span class='spantitle'>" . $row['ptitle'] . "</span>" .
    "<span class='spanuser'>" . $row['uname'] . "</span>" .
    "</div>\n";
}
echo $items;
```

Output is ok except first row where I see the date - 1.1.1970 - but there is no any row in `posts` with that date. Plus - in the same row `ptitle` is missing.

Also, is there a better way to create this query, avoiding `as` keyword ?

desired output (single block):

```
<div class='itemp' data-id=116 data-user='JOHN SMITH'><span class='spandate'>01-12-2017</span><span class='spantitle'>BLUE SKY</span><span class='spanuser'>JOHN SMITH</span></div>
```

Comment: 1.1.1970 is the Default date for unix time, but no idea why it is you first row

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause, but no aggregating functions. I'm not sure what we're supposed to do with that.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Without knowing the data stored in your databsae I would guess there is a user, which is a mod without any post. Please avoid mixing up several questions in one post - you can avaoid the `as` totally but than you have to change the fieldnames to get access to the values in the while loop, more common is to use the `as` notation.

Comment: Er, you can avoid the `as` keyword by omitting the `as` keyword.

Comment: @Strawberry, please explain your last comment.

Comment: `SELECT a AS b` is the same as `SELECT a b`

Comment: @Michael, oh, i see, yuu're right, there is a user without posts. Thanks. What would be the right query for that scenario - avoid users without posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, is there a better way to create this query, avoiding as keyword ?

Yes (but not better in my opinion):

```
SELECT users.id,
  users.name,
  posts.id,
  posts.date,
  posts.title,
  posts.user
FROM users
LEFT 
JOIN posts  
  ON users.id = posts.user
WHERE users.role = 'mod'
GROUP 
  BY posts.title;
```

But as mentioned in the comments you have to modify your while loop in this case to get access to your values. But I think this is not a better way of writing this query cause it makes it harder to read.

Regarding your `JOIN` problem. this depends on what your result should be (I guess you only want `users` with `posts` ). So you should take a look at `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. You will get only results which also have `posts` entrys.
Due to the nature of `LEFT JOIN` all entrys on the left table (in your case `users`) will be used, even if they don´t have an entry in the `posts` table.
`INNER JOIN` will only return results which match results in both tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try with `inner join`.

Comment: This query perpeutates an abuse of the GROUP BY clause.